# If $\alpha \preceq \beta$ then there is a unique ordinal $\gamma$ such that $\alpha + \gamma = \beta$

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, ordinals

I tried to prove this proposition, if $\alpha \preceq \beta$ then there is a unique ordinal $\gamma$ such that $\alpha + \gamma = \beta$, by order type not by transfinite induction.

My attempt:

- $W = \{ \xi \in \beta \mid \alpha \preceq \xi \}$ is a set of ordinals so, $W$ is a woset.
- Every woset is order isomorphic to a unique ordinal, therefore, exist a unique ordinal $\gamma$ such that, $W$ and $\gamma$ are ordered isomorphic.

My problem:
I strongly believe that, $\gamma$ is the solution but I cannot prove that, $\alpha + \gamma = \beta$.

Def: $\prec := \in$. The ordinal addition is defined by induction.

I have read some similar questions. For example, [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3831046/if-alpha-beta-there-exists-a-ordinal-gamma-such-that-alpha-gamma) just talk about transfinite induction (limit case) and [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3710453/for-ordinals-delta-and-beta-if-delta-in-or-beta-then-there-exists?noredirect=1&lq=1) just talk about the uniqueness. I hope your helps.

Comment: You start with the inductive definition of ordinal addition and you want to prove a theorem using order-types rather than induction. So at some point, you'll need to connect these two views of ordinal addition.In terms of order-types, addition is defined as "$\xi+\eta$ is the order-type of a copy of $\xi$ followed by a (disjoint) copy of $\eta$." I recommend proving that this definition and the inductive definition of addition agree. Once you have that fact available, your proposed proof will work.

Comment: Hi Andreas, thank you very much. I did answered the question by the way. Start at inductive definition then show that's equivalent to order - type definition.

Answer (score 1):

Your demonstration that $W$ has the order type of an ordinal is correct. Once you have that $W$ is isomorphic to a unique ordinal $\gamma$, you're basically done, as $\alpha + \gamma = \beta$ by [the definition of ordinal addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Addition):

> *The union of two disjoint well-ordered sets $S$ and $T$ can be well-ordered. The order-type of that union is the ordinal which results from adding the order-types of $S$ and $T$. If two well-ordered sets are not already disjoint, then they can be replaced by order-isomorphic disjoint sets, e.g. replace $S$ by $\{ 0 \} × S$ and $T$ by $\{ 1 \} × T$. This way, the well-ordered set $S$ is written "to the left" of the well-ordered set T, meaning one defines an order on $S \cup T$ in which every element of $S$ is smaller than every element of $T$. The sets $S$ and $T$ themselves keep the ordering they already have.*

By your definition of $W$, $$W := \{ \xi \in \beta | \alpha = \xi \text{ or } \alpha \in \xi \},$$ it's clear that $\beta$ is the disjoint union of $\alpha = \{ \xi \in \beta | \xi \in \alpha \}$ with $W$.
But the disjoint union of $\alpha$ with $W$ is order-isomorphic to the disjoint union of $\{ 0 \} \times \alpha$ with $\{ 1 \} \times \gamma$ equipped with the dictionary order, since $\gamma$ is the unique ordinal with the order type of $W$. This is the definition of what it means for $\alpha + \gamma$ to equal $\beta$.

If you do it this way, no induction argument is required. The heart of the question is whether there is an argument that works--and I quote--

> *"by order type not transfinite induction,"*

and this would seem to be what the original post is asking for.

Comment: The ordinal addition is defined by recursion. Why we have $\alpha + \gamma = \beta$ (basically?). I can understand but can not give any formal explanation. Could you please help me in more detail (formally)?

Comment: @ChauLong You can use the definition of ordinal addition from that link, instead of whichever one you are using. If you were demanding that answers use one particular definition of ordinal addition, you should have specified that in your original question.

Comment: We are taking in the same definition, no particular one.

Comment: @ChauLong Only the second definition in the link is inductive. I updated my post above with an explicit formal argument based on the *first* definition, which defines ordinal addition via the disjoint union of well ordered sets. Transfinite induction is not necessary to complete your argument.

Comment: Hi Rivers, your "first definition" is my below theorem. My original question based on inductive definition (in my opinion, this is the only one "real" definition) and I was trying to explain that by order type. Anyway, we both have similar thinking now and I am happy with this. Thank you very much.

Comment: @chaulong I don’t understand. You copied out (with some cosmetic changes) the definition of ordinal addition from the Wikipedia link I provided you weeks ago, typed it up as “your” below “theorem”, and you think it proves that addition of ordinals *could not* be defined in this way? And your original question asked if uniqueness of ordinal subtraction could be proven by order type, rather than transfinite induction. It has no apparent relationship to your (very idiosyncratic) opinion that the inductive definition of ordinal addition is the Only “Real” Definition.

Comment: Hi Rivers, Firstly, "my below theorem" means my posted theorem, I am not the guy who invent the theorem (I am not a mathematician). Secondly, you can refer the theorem in many different books (e.g Jech - Set Theory). You can also refer the theorem on this Stack Exchange site at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2982516/the-sum-of-two-well-ordered-sets-is-isomorphic-to-the-sum-of-corresponding-ordin. Lastly, in my opinion, the addition definition should be defined by induction and (you understood my meaning right) should not be defined by that way (your Wiki def).

Comment: It is just a property, a feature, ... which we can derive and prove. And once again, just my personal opinion. I am sorry if there is any mistake or wrong explanation (my English is not very good).

Comment: @ChauLong Everyone's entitled to their own preferences regarding definitions and axioms. But it's perfectly valid, and quite common, to start out by *defining* ordinal addition using the dictionary order on the disjoint union. In which case one could then "derive and prove" the inductive "property/feature" of ordinal addition as a theorem from *that* definition. There's no objective reason to say one setup is more or less valid than the other--they are, in fact, equivalent in every respect, since either one can be proven from the other.

Comment: @chaulong Personally, I find the order type definition of ordinal addition equally intuitive--and much more user-friendly--compared to the inductive definition. And although you claim to disagree, your original question suggests that you've been struggling with some of the less user-friendly aspects of the inductive definition yourself.

Comment: Hi River, inductive def is "user-friendly" according to my personal view. "Disjoint union def" is more "user-friendly" according to your personal view. No one better than another in general. Once again, we both have similar thinking and I am happy with this. Thank you very much.

Comment: @chaulong But if the inductive definition is so user-friendly, how come you weren’t able to use it to show that $\alpha + \gamma = \beta$? Whereas it was easy-peasy to prove  $\alpha + \gamma = \beta$ using the order type definition. Took me three sentences (second paragraph after blockquote).

Comment: Hi Rivers, It is so "user-friendly" not because of the question $\alpha + \gamma = \beta$. You may know about similar inductive definition of product and power operators on ordinal class. It is more useful by the way although there are some difficulties out there like $\alpha + \gamma = \beta$. However, it is alright, isn't it?

Comment: @ChauLong Maybe there's a specific instance where the inductive definition is nicer to work with than the explicit definition via order types, although I can't think of one offhand. But induction proofs tend to be slower and give less of an intuitive picture of what's going on. And in practice, the inductive definition is *not what's actually used for computations*, unless you're the kind of person who finds the 100th term of the arithmetic sequence $a_1 = 5, a_n = 3 + a_{n-1}$ by calculating $a_2, ..., a_{99}, a_{100}$ recursively, rather than with the explicit formula $a_n = 5 + 3(n-1)$.

Comment: Hi Rivers, your example is just so small compare to what induction can do. Obviously, there are some disadvantages when we use induction and not only induction but also any other tool. However, the advantages of induction are so many. You can easily find out in your practices and even in your example. Computers and programming are working more in inductive way than explicit formula. In fact, there is not easy to find out the formula like $a_n = 5 + 3(n-1)$ generally and that's why all of programming languages have loop functions like "for", "do", "while", ... I hope my thinking can help.

Comment: @ChauLong My example about arithmetic sequences was specific to this context, to explain that the inductive definition of ordinal addition is *not actually used to add ordinals in applications*. In applications, we use the definition by concatenation of order types in the lexicographic order, **always, every time,** instead of saying "To add $\gamma$ to $\alpha$, first I will add 1 to $\alpha$, then I will add 1 to that, then I will add 1 again to that..." and so on, $\gamma$ times in a row. I highly doubt that that's how *you personally* perform ordinal addition.

Comment: @ChauLong And frequently, as in your question that motivated this discussion, concatenating order types leads to shorter and clearer proofs as well. The inductive definition is really pretty awkward for many basic, fundamental things--you weren't even able to use it to prove something really simple about ordinal subtraction! In the context of that failure, I'm struggling to take your claim that the inductive definition of ordinal addition is not just "truer" but *more user-friendly* at all seriously, no matter how useful induction can be in other, irrelevant contexts.

Comment: Hi Rivers, you are going so far. Comeback to my question, I started at inductive definition and develop further steps like properties/theorems/features, ... for my future investigation. As I mentioned above, there are some difficulties like $\alpha + \gamma = \beta$ when I use induction and that is the reason why I posted and proved the below theorem. In the future, I can apply the theorem to solve something if I see they are easier for approaching or I can use the inductive def to prove them if I see they are more convenient.

Comment: Your def is more useful in some specific situation (not all cases) and it is more "user-friendly" by your view (not mine). Once again, start at induction and develop more properties/lemmas/features ... like the below theorem for futher developnent is my way. Many people have similar thinking as I have refered above. Logically, I am happy with this way and I see it's not neccessary to continue our discussion here. It's too far and we should avoid posting cmt on this chanel. Maybe we can chat for better understand each other. Thank you very much and have a nice weekend.

Comment: @ChauLong You're right, this comment thread is getting too long. If I post under "your below theorem" every reason what you're saying is wrong and makes no sense--for instance, the fact that you didn't *prove* "your below theorem", just stated it, and you didn't even use induction in stating it--it will be easier for other people who come later to instantly spot the multiple errors in your statements in this discussion. Thank you very much and have a nice weekend

Answer (score 0):

I have proved one theorem:

If two disjoint ordered sets, $(W_1, \preceq_1)$ order isomorphic to $\alpha$ and $(W_2, \preceq_2)$ order isomorphic to $\gamma$, then ordered sum of the two ordered sets, $(W_1, \preceq_1) \oplus (W_2, \preceq_2)$, order isomorphic to $\alpha + \gamma$.

Def: $\forall x,y \in (W_1 \cup W_2, \preceq) = (W_1, \preceq_1) \oplus (W_2, \preceq_2): x \preceq y$ is defined:

1. $x,y \in W_1 \wedge x \preceq_1 y$ or
2. $x,y \in W_2 \wedge x \preceq_2 y$ or
3. $x \in W_1 \wedge y \in W_2$.

Back to the problem above, from $\alpha \cup W = \beta$ and $W$ order isomorphic to $\gamma$ so, $\alpha \oplus W = \beta$ order isomorphic to $\alpha + \gamma$ by the theorem. Therefore, $\alpha + \gamma = \beta$.

Just find out a way to explain.

Comment: I’d like to point out that this answer does not use the inductive definition of ordinal addition, but relies on the order type definition. Except insofar as the two definitions are equivalent, this would seem to undermine the claim that the inductive definition is the more user-friendly of the two.

Comment: This is not a "theorem" you have "proven", it's a statement you have made. Nowhere is the order isomorphism demonstrated or proven. **In particular, nowhere is a proof *by induction* given that there is an order isomorphism between these two sets.** So your claim that it's a direct consequence of the inductive definition is clearly, blatantly false.